# ошибка ModuleNotFoundError при импорте класса из модуля

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт

У меня есть файл `test1.py`, расположенный по такому пути `/project/dir1/` и в котором находится следующий код:

```
from colors import Colors  # модуль colors.py находится в папке вместе с test1.py

class Test1:
    ....
```

Есть еще и второй файл `test2.py`, лежащий по пути `/project/dir2/` и содержащий следующий код:

```
from dir1.test1 import Test1
...
```

Когда я запускаю модуль `test1.py`, то он выполняется без ошибок. Но когда я запускаю модуль  `test2.py`, то мне интерпретатор выдает ошибку - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colors'` (который используется в модуле `test1.py`). В чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 1):

Решил следующим способом (не знаю на сколько это корректно и правильно, но другого решения не нашел)

Добавил в переменную окружения путь до проекта

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/project
```

и теперь модуль импортирую следующим способом

```
from .colors import Colors
```

Comment: Не забудьте отметить данный ответ как верный, чтобы закрыть вопрос и не засорять список незакрытых ;)